# I'm trying to process a text file and I keep getting my variables assigned to the wrong data

Tags: python, text-files, readline

I'm doing an assignment where I have to open input and output files, read the data and process it, and write it into the output file. The code is supposed to assign letter grades to students based on whether they are undergrad or grad, then write their names and grades to a new file. I keep running into an issue where after I input the filenames, the variable assignment is shifted and I get a ValueError telling me that a String is not an int. My guess is that my for loop is taking a variable and shifting everything down, but I have no idea how to fix this.

```
# prompt the user to enter an input filename
try:
    filename_one = input('Please enter the name of the input data file: ')

# if the file is invalid, print an error message and prompt the user to enter another filename
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Unknown input filename detected ' + filename_one + '.')

filename_two = input('Please enter the name of the output data file: ')

input_file = open(filename_one, 'r')
output_file = open(filename_two, 'w')

for line in input_file:
    # assign variables to the data from the input file
    under_or_grad = input_file.readline()
    name = input_file.readline()
    grade = int(input_file.readline())

    # write student name to output file
    output_file.write(name)

    # figure out if the student is an undergrad or a grad
    # assign grade to student
    if under_or_grad == 'GRAD':
        if 95 <= grade <= 100:
            grade = 'H'
        elif 80 <= grade <= 94:
            grade = 'P'
        elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
            grade = 'L'
        elif 0 <= grade <= 69:
            grade = 'F'
    elif under_or_grad == 'UNDERGRAD':
        if 90 <= grade <= 100:
            grade = 'A'
        elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
            grade = 'B'
        elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
            grade = 'C'
        elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
            grade = 'D'
        elif 0 <= grade <= 59:
            grade = 'F'

    # write output grade to output file
output_file.write(str(grade))
next_line = input_file.readline()

output_file.close()
```

Here's an example of the data I'm working with (without the blank lines between each):

GRAD

Old Jane

76

I'm trying to get it to write this into the output file (same blank line thing):

Old Jane

L

Here's the error message just in case:

```
grade = int(input_file.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'GRAD\n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing different file reading techniques: `for line in input_file` and `readline`. Take a look on different ways of reading text files [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/). Probably the `readline` in `while True` loop will be the best in your situation. You'll need to replace `for line in input_file` with `while True` and probably remove `next_line=input_file.readline()` at the bottom (unless the records for different students are separated from each other by a blank line). Also, you need to give a proper indentation to `output_file.write` (and `next_line=input_file.readline()` if necessary), because right now they are not inside the loop:

```py
while True:
    # assign variables to the data from the input file
    under_or_grad = input_file.readline()
    if not under_or_grad:
        break
    name = input_file.readline()
    if not name:
        break
    grade_str = input_file.readline()
    if not grade_str:
        break
    grade = int(grade)

    # write student name to output file
    output_file.write(name)

    # figure out if the student is an undergrad or a grad
    # assign grade to student
    if under_or_grad == 'GRAD':
        if 95 <= grade <= 100:
            grade = 'H'
        elif 80 <= grade <= 94:
            grade = 'P'
        elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
            grade = 'L'
        elif 0 <= grade <= 69:
            grade = 'F'
    elif under_or_grad == 'UNDERGRAD':
        if 90 <= grade <= 100:
            grade = 'A'
        elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
            grade = 'B'
        elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
            grade = 'C'
        elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
            grade = 'D'
        elif 0 <= grade <= 59:
            grade = 'F'

    # write output grade to output file
    output_file.write(str(grade))
    # Use this only if there is a blank line between records
    next_line = input_file.readline()
    if not next_line:
         break
```

Comment: I was doing some research on how to make my loop not do this and it would make sense that I mixed up my syntax while trying to fix the error. I went ahead and replaced the for loop with a while True loop and fixed the indentation at the end, though I have run into a new issue when running the program: `grade = int(grade)
NameError: name 'grade' is not defined` at line 27.

Comment: Never mind, fixed that. Now the problem has evolved to the program writing the name and the number grades in the output file without processing them.